# How to accept different patterns of options in a PHP function?

Tags: php, function, extend, operands

I have got a function which should accept either an array, or a string and another string. Other operand types are to be declined.

How do I do that?

Comment: Check my answer and mark as accepted if it's help to resolve your problem. Let me know if you still have any issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your function such a way that it should only accept arrays or string and if it's find another operand then It will be automatically exit from the php function.

Below is just PHP script that you can identify manually into your PHP function.

Sample of PHP Function:

```
 function testStringAndArray($arg) {
        if(is_array($arg)|| is_string($arg)) {
            //Do Processing
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouln't be throwing an [InvalidArgumentException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) be more sensible? The actual processing might return `false`

Comment: This is just a sample, you can first check the operand type and if it's not valid (i.e String or array) you can do further processing as per your requirements. I hope you may get the flow to achieve your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the is_array() function of php to check if the given option in an array or string.

[Check it here is_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have any code you can put in the question.

As I understood from the requirement your function should look something like below

```
function($arrayOrString, $string){
    if((is_array($arrayOrString) || is_string($arrayOrString)) && is_string($string)){
         // do something here
    }else{
         return false;
    }
}
```

Ref: [is_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php)
& [is_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php)

Comment: Wouln't be throwing an [InvalidArgumentException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php) be more sensible? The actual processing might return `false`

Comment: Why it will throw exception? I am already checking the type of argument. Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: If the type does't match, the function returns `false`. Now the `//do something here` might also return `false`. How to distinguish? One way would be to throw an exception (not check for one).

Comment: Throwing exception is a way we can handle the request to the function. But the requirement is quite not the same.And `// do something` was just a statement where the coder can write something to do.

Answer (score 0):

Attached, functional sample with "No param", string param and array param.

```
<?php

class Speaker {
    public function sayHello($person = null) 
    {
        // I will display hello something base on parameter type.
        $this->render(
            $this->prepareParams($person);
        );
    }

    private function prepareParams($param = null) {
        //Default value
        if(is_null($param)) {
            $param = 'World';
        }
        else if(is_array($param)) {
            //Merge all item to one string with coma separator
            $param = implode(', ', $param);
        }

        return $param;
    }

    private function render(string $target) {
        echo "Hello ".$target;
    }
}

$tester = new Speaker();

$this->sayHello();
$this->sayHello('Yanis');

$this->sayHello(['Yanis', 'thomas','roman']);
```

You can deal with default parameter to manage your second optional parameter such as :

```
if(!is_null($mySecondParameter)) // I can use it Because he is defined.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just thought too complicated.
I wanted something like

```
public myFunction(array $arg1) {
   ...
}
public myFunction(string $arg1, string $arg2) extends myFunction {
   ...
}
```

But it's much easier with something like

```
public myFunction($arg1, $arg2 = null) {
   if(is_array($arg1)) {
      ...
   }
   if(is_string($arg1) && is_string($arg2)) {
      ...
   }
```